# The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached. Xcode 11.5

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer, sideloading

I updated Xcode to 11.5 from 11.4 soon after the update I'm unable to run the apps on my physical device which is also currently running the latest IOS 13.5. When I try running the app an error shows up saying 
**"-402620383--The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached."** 
even though I have no apps running on my phone.

So far I've tried,

- Clearing all the provisioning profiles from, Window >> Devices and simulator >> Right clicking on the device.
- Unpairing iPhone from the computer and re-pairing it.
- Removing my free developer account from Xcode and logging back.
- Restarting my computer
- Cleaned the project

[Cleared all apps in iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSvt3.png)

[Cleared all provisioning profiles from the iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc0zL.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242678/xcode-error-the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-re

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work

Comment: I had this problem, but there was no results for `MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker`. However, this was because one of the answers at the link above at Ask Different was my problem.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I had the same exact issue, even though I uninstalled all apps installed through Xcode. I found out that after updating to Xcode 11.5 and iOS 13.5, some of the other apps (not developed by me) are counted toward the limit.

Open Console app on Macbook and catch logs while trying to install an app from Xcode. Under Devices on the left > Choose your iPhone device > Then search for `MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker` and something like:

```
[MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker _onQueue_addReferenceForApplicationIdentifier:bundle:error:]: 182: This device has reached the maximum number of installed apps using a free developer profile: {(
    "<bundleid>",
    "<bundleid>",
    "<bundleid>"
)}
```

Instead of `<bundleid>` there are gonna be concrete ids that are counted toward free app limit. I found out, which app are those, deleted them and everything worked like a charm after that.

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU! This fixed it! Turns out that all "offloaded" apps were counted as "free developer profile apps" including: Voice Memos, Google Docs, and Shortcuts. Once I deleted or reinstalled, it worked!

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent 24 hours looking for a fix on this! I can finally go to sleep!

Comment: this bug is just ridiculous.

Comment: I cringe with this bug.

Comment: How is this done: "Open Console app on Macbook and catch logs" ?

Comment: Apple is now more than a trillion dollar company. This is the kind of rookie mistake I'd make in my code.

Comment: @HlawulekaMAS Press cmd + space and type in console.app

Answer (score 34):

This is not a bug. Apple restricts free developer accounts, permitting the installation of only three apps on a device.

An easier way is to delete apps through the Xcode devices window, instead of searching through the log file.  In Xcode 13.1, the devices window is accessible from the Window > Devices and Simulators menu item, or by using the <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

[image: Devices window]

Use the delete button to remove apps under the same account.

> When targeting devices running iOS 13.3.1, tvOS 13.3.1, watchOS 6.1, or later using a free Apple Developer account, app extensions incorrectly count against the limit of three apps installed simultaneously. When this happens, Xcode reports an error: “The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.” (59264389) (FB7568073)
>
> Workaround: Delete apps signed with your free account from your device and also remove any associated provisioning profiles from the device using Xcode’s Devices window. If your app contains more than two app extensions, remove them to remain under the three app limit.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_4-release-notes

Answer (score 21):

In Addition to Artur Peplinski answer, all apps effected are offloaded apps. Apple include a feature on iOS 11 that automatically offload unused app after 14 days. You can disable this feature in the iOS settings. If you load them again or delete them, it works

Comment: I have soooooo many apps , this will take forever

Comment: @frazras, yeah me too, this bug is very annoying

Comment: I updated my Xcode to 11.6 and the problem still happens. 

Comment: Offloaded apps can be removed without necessity to download them before it (long tap doesn't show "Remove app" button for them). Just enter edit screen mode (long tap on any app and try to move it on screen to make cross in top-left corner appear). It helped me to remove more than 150 offloaded apps in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the Apple Developer Program but still have this issue, try this:

## 1

Go to Xcode preferences

[image]

## 2

Navigate to 'Accounts'

[image]

## 3

Open 'Manage Certificates'

[image]

## 4

Add this certificate

[image]