# Xcode 11.6 - Unable to install in Iphone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I cannot install an application on my device. Every time I run the application, I get an "Unable to install" message, I don't know if it is a version or OS problem, I will leave an image:

[image]

And here are the details:

[image]

The version of Xcode is 11.6 and the version of my Iphone (SE 2020) is 13.6.1, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you read the error message that starts, "The maximum number..."?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode/61978102#61978102

Comment: @PhillipMills I followed the steps of the publication, and now I get another error: Failure Reason: iPhone Des has denied the launch request.
Internal launch error: process launch failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch DesDev.testing because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.

Comment: @PhillipMills Forget it my friend, it's already solved, at the end I followed the steps of the publication and I deleted the applications installed in the device, I granted permissions and it worked, but it generates a doubt to me, there is a certain amount of applications that one can have in the device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached. Xcode 11.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode)

Comment: @gcharita yep, solved