# Please delete apps signed with your free account from this device to remain under the limit

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I built an app on my computer using Xcode(version 12.3) and I want to try running it on my iPhone 8.
When I run the Swift(version 5.3.2) code,

**I get the error:**

```
Please delete apps signed with your free account from this device to remain under the limit.
```

I just enrolled in the Apple Developer Program two days ago and it's not a free account.
This error occurs when I try to install a fourth app on my iPhone.

I have tried the following:

- Clearing the provisioning profiles from, `Window >> Devices and simulator >> Unpair Device`.
- Rebooting my Mac computer.
- Remove all three of my apps installed on my iPhone.
- Rebooting my iPhone.
- Reinstall 4 apps to my iPhone (
  Reconnect my iPhone to my Mac computer and trust my Mac computer with my iPhone).

After trying the above, I couldn't install the 4th app.

How can I solve it?

Regards,

Izuho Suginaka.

Comment: Please try this solution, I think it will work. [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode)

Comment: @son, thank you for your answer. 
But can I install more than 4 apps if I'm enrolled in the Apple Developer Program? I know that I can install up to 3 apps with a free account ...

Comment: Yes, you can. An enrolled account allows you to create unlimited apps.

Comment: @son, I can't do that with a enrolled account. (>_<)

Comment: Hm, so weird. Maybe your account has not enrolled yet, cause a payment will take a few days. Can you login to Apple Developer site to create a bundle id?

Comment: Thank you! solved! I tried the following:

-Uninstall Xcode
・ Apple Developer Program site >> Getting Started with Provisioning Profiles
・ Apple Developer Program site >> Keys generation

The above did not solve the problem, but after that, I solved it by doing the following.
Click the project file from the left side of Xcode,

TARGETS >> Signing & Capabilities >> + Capability Click>> Sign in with Apple

I can now install more than 4 apps. thanks!