# Webdriver-agent app is not installed after build successful message in xcode

Tags: xcode, appium-ios

mac os: Ventura 13.1
xcode : 14
appium : 1.22.3
Homebrew : 3.6.12
iphone : 11 pro(ios 16)

```
WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj % xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=00008030-00052DDE0E84802E' -allowProvisioningUpdates test
 xcodebuild[28997:446901] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
 xcodebuild[28997:446901] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
Command line invocation:
    /Users/rhitvik.mittai/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project "WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme" WebDriverAgentRunner "-destination id=00008030-00052DDE0E84802E -allowProvisioningUpdates" test

User defaults from command line:
    destination id = 00008030-00052DDE0E84802E -allowProvisioningUpdates
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action 'WebDriverAgentRunner'.
```

i want the webdriver agent app to be downloaded in my iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem where it was building successfully but not actually downloading my phone. I was reading this documentation: https://appium.github.io/appium-xcuitest-driver/4.16/wda-custom-server/

And if you aren't already, build it from the menu like this:

Select WebDriverAgentRunner project
Select your real phone/Simulator you'd like to run automated tests on as build target
Select Product->Test from the main menu

And it should tell you that there's an error:
Please delete apps signed with your free account from this device to remain under the limit.

And that's because free developer account are only allowed to download 3 Xcode apps to work on for development on 1 phone. So then I followed this: [The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached. Xcode 11.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode)

And from that page, the answer is you can use:
Open Console app on Macbook and catch logs while trying to install an app from Xcode. Under Devices on the left > Choose your iPhone device > Then search for MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker and something like:

[MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker _onQueue_addReferenceForApplicationIdentifier:bundle:error:]: 182: This device has reached the maximum number of installed apps using a free developer profile:

1. "bundleid",
2. "bundleid",
3. "bundleid"

Instead of  there are gonna be concrete ids that are counted toward free app limit.

So you can use that to see which apps count towards that limit, delete those apps so that you can make room and try to build and test WebDriverAgentRunner again